# Flutter - Unhandled Exception while reading data from local database

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

Im developing a flutter app, and i need save a list of operations in local database and show it in a list view, this is my class Operation:

```
class Operation {
  String _description = "";
  bool _isEntry = true;
  String _date = "";
  double _amount = 0.0;

  String get description => _description;
  bool get isEntry => _isEntry;
  String get date => _date;
  double get amount => _amount;

  set description(String description) {
    if(description.isNotEmpty) {
      _description = description;
    }
  }

  set date(String date) {
    if(date.isNotEmpty) {
      _date = date;
    }
  }

  set amount(double amount) {
    _amount = amount;
  }

  set isEntry(bool isEntry) {
    _isEntry = isEntry;
  }

  var now = DateTime.now();
  var formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

  Operation() {
    _amount = 0.0;
    _description = "";
    _isEntry = false;
    _date = formatter.format(now);
  }

  Operation.withData({amount = 0.0, description = "", isEntry = false, date = ""}) {
    _amount = _amount;
    _description = description;
    _isEntry = isEntry;
    _date = date;
  }

  Operation.fromMap(map) {
    _amount = map["amount"];
    _description = map["description"];
    _isEntry = map["isEntry"] == 0;
    _date = map["date"];
  }

  toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map["amount"] = _amount;
    map["description"] = _description;
    map["isEntry"] = _isEntry ? 0 : 1;
    map["date"] = _date;
    return map;
  }
  
}
```

When i open the app, and the screen loads my operations from local storage, im reciving this error:

```
====================================================================================================
E/flutter ( 6175): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'
E/flutter ( 6175): #0      new Operation.fromMap (package:flutter_example/model/operation.dart:52:5)
E/flutter ( 6175): #1      LocalDatabase.getOperationList (package:flutter_example/provider/local_db.dart:60:39)
E/flutter ( 6175): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6175): #2      new MonitorBloc.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_example/bloc/monitor_bloc.dart:22:30)
E/flutter ( 6175): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6175): #3      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:226:13)
E/flutter ( 6175): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6175):
```

And this is my Database class:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import '../model/operation.dart';
import '../model/operations.dart';

class LocalDatabase {
  static LocalDatabase helper = LocalDatabase._createInstance();

  LocalDatabase._createInstance();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    _database ??= await initializeDatabase();
    return _database!;
  }

  String operationTable = "operation_table";
  String colId = "id";
  String colAmount = "amount";
  String colDescription = "description";
  String colIsEntry = "isEntry";
  String colDate = "date";

  _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) {
    db.execute("""
       CREATE TABLE $operationTable (
           $colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
           $colAmount NUM,
           $colDescription TEXT,
           $colDate TEXT,
           $colIsEntry INT
          );
    """);
  }

  Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = "${directory.path}operations_2.db";
    return openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
  }

  Future<int> insertOperation(Operation operation) async {
    Database? db = await database;
    int result = await db.insert(operationTable, operation.toMap());
    notify(result.toString(), operation);
    return result;
  }

  Future<OperationsCollection> getOperationList() async {
    Database db = await database;
    List<Map<String, Object?>> operationMapList =
    await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $operationTable;");
    OperationsCollection operationsCollection = OperationsCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i < operationMapList.length; i++) {
      Operation operation = Operation.fromMap(operationMapList[i]);

      operationsCollection.insertOperationOfId(operationMapList[i][colId].toString(), operation);
    }
    return operationsCollection;
  }

  // Stream

  notify(String operationId, Operation? operation) async {
    _controller?.sink.add([operationId, operation]);
  }

  Stream get stream {
    _controller ??= StreamController.broadcast();
    return _controller!.stream;
  }

  dispose() {
    if (_controller != null) {
      if (!_controller!.hasListener) {
        _controller!.close();
        _controller = null;
      }
    }
  }

  static StreamController? _controller;
}
```

I don't know where is the error, if is while the operation is saved or while i read from database.
Any ideia?

Comment: looks like `_amount` should be an `int` not `double`

Comment: i tried it, but when i load the screen all values came as 0

Comment: are the values in the table double or int?

Comment: i dont know a way to see the database, but i tried created the column as int, but dont work

Comment: add `print(map);` for now in `Operation.fromMap(map)` and add the output in the answer

Comment: When i read the data, the print was:
I/flutter ( 8633): {id: 2, amount: 5000, description: salario, date: 2022-11-27, isEntry: 1}
I/flutter ( 8633): {id: 1, amount: 45, description: conta de luz, date: 2022-11-27, isEntry: 0}
I put a print on view component, and it recive 0 as amount, any idea?

Comment: ```
ListView getOperationListView(OperationsCollection operationsCollection){
    if(operationsCollection.length() > 0) {
      print(operationsCollection.getOperationAtIndex(0).amount);
      print(operationsCollection.getOperationAtIndex(0).description);
    }
```

i made this print, and got the description, but the amount is 0:
I/flutter (12264): 0
I/flutter (12264): salario

Comment: I found the error, my withData method was this:
Operation.withData({amount = 0.0, description = "", isEntry = false, date = ""}) {
    _amount = _amount;
    _description = description;
    _isEntry = isEntry;
    _date = date;
  }

I wasnt change the amount value
Thank you dude!